# How to forward X over SSH to run gnome-terminal remotely? (18.04)

Tags: xorg, gnome-terminal, remote

It runs remotely in version 14.04 but not in version 18.04.
All graphics applications (gnome-todo, firefox etc) are lunched remotely via SSH.
However, when I run gnome-terminal remotely via SSH, it run in non-remote native gnome-desktop.

Comment: Please show the command you're using..    Normally it is `ssh -Y sysname` to get an X11-capable connection.  Are you saying this is what you are using but itis not working?  If so, is there any error message?

Comment: Yes, I use putty for ssh with enabling X11 forwarding. every apps except gnome-terminal are forwarded to remote X11 server. when I run gnome-terminal remotely via SSH, it lunched on host desktop. there is not any error message.

Comment: This happens to me too. Maybe you need not run `gnome-terminal` remotely. Try to start another (and third ...) `putty` alongside the first one and run the command lines there. Or you can try another terminal emulator program. `lxterminal` and good old `xterm` open their windows where they should.

Comment: I suspect it's related to this [Run true multiple process instances of gnome-terminal](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/201915/65304) i.e. it works if you don't have a running instance of `gnome-terminal-server` on the remote machine

Comment: @steeldriver, I can verify that `gnome-terminal-server` is running on my remote machine (Lubuntu 18.04 LTS). (I have not tested turning it off. Have you tested that?)

Comment: @sudodus only on 16.04 so far (at least, I was able to run a forwarded `gnome-terminal` in the case that there was no desktop session at all on the remote server). Did you try using the `--app-id` switch as described in the linked answer?

Comment: @steeldriver, No I did not try that. Let us wait for feed-back from the OP.

Comment: @DonghoonYu, Please let us know if you have any success according to the tips in our comments :-)

Comment: @steeldriver, According to the link you taught, I have run gnome-terminal with the --disable-factory and --app-id on SSH.
In both options, It was launched on a PC running SSH as I wanted.
Thank you for solving my problem. :)

Comment: Excellent discussion and answer to this question at:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/407831/how-can-i-launch-gnome-terminal-remotely-on-my-headless-server-fails-to-launch

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As steeldriver said in a comment above, new gnome-terminal instance behaves like some insipid Windows or Mac program; it only sends a message to the existing, running gnome-terminal to create a new window. 
To run gnome-terminal on a new client PC, use the --disable-factory or --app-id option.

Comment: `--disable-factory` Isn't supported anymore on version 3.34.0-1 on debian. I'm also unable to find more information about `--app-id` within the man pages.

Answer (score 0):

This command works for me. I had to add the `--display` argument for Centos 7 (Newer gnome-terminal).

```
ssh -Y HOST bash -l -c gnome-terminal --display=${DISPLAY} < /dev/null > /dev/null  2>&1 &
```